# What would be the code for serial number authentication?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, authentication, copy-protection, serial-number

I am programming in visual basic 2008
I would like to set up serial numebers for software im developing. I would like to prevent software theft by ensuring that each purchased copy has a unique serial number that can only be used once. How would i create this so 
a.) The serial numeber can only be used once
b.) The software cannot run without a correct serial number
c.) The serial number verification box pops up on ONLY the first use of the program and goes away after correct serial number is entered
d.) a serial number generation and verification program

Comment: Lots of duplicates. Try search SO.

Comment: I'm not sure what this is called so I don't know

Comment: It's called licensing or software protection.

Comment: Thanks. How do you do this in Visual Basic 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very vague and dosen't have just a single answer.   There are many, many, ways to accomplish what it is you are asking.  The previous answers are attempting to push you to search Stack Overflow for other questions which may provide you assistance as to other ways the problem has been solved.

Have a quick look at the 'copy-protection' tag - there are many answers there that can help you on your way.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copy-protection

Regards
Luke

Comment: Thanks Luke, by any chance do you live in florida? Also, what would ou personally recommend I do in copy protection

Comment: Hi RCProgramming, sorry, No I do not live in Florida.  I live in Australia.   Personally, I think copy protection is a waste of time.  There is no way to 'prevent' software theft, only reduce it by making it slightly harder.  Visual Basic is quite easy to decompile, which means any copy protection scheme that you do come up with can be circumvented very easily.   Apologies if that wasn't what you wanted to hear.  :)   Best of luck with your development.

Comment: I have created my own mathematical method of password protection which I'd apply to this. I don't believe its in use by anyone else yet. Do you have any idea where I can get the code for this and a serial number generator

Comment: Hi RCProgramming,  If it's not in use by anyone else, you'll have a very hard time finding someone who has written the code already. :)   Generally i'd expect the serial numbers to have some correlation to your password correct?  Otherwise you can generate them randomly. (although if you were doing that you wouldn't need them at all as they wouldn't feed into your algorithm)